# Game Center Not Properly Working. Swift, Sprite Kit

Tags: swift

I recently tried to add Game Center to my Sprite Kit Game, but it's not working properly.

When the game starts in the simulator, the Game Center login page does show up. When I start the game on my phone it does not. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
//GameViewController.Swift
import GameKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

var bannerView:ADBannerView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Presenting scene without using GameScene.sks
    let skView = view as! SKView
    let myScene = GameScene(size: skView.frame.size)
    myScene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

    skView.presentScene(myScene)
    authenticateLocalPlayer()

}

//initiate gamecenter
func authenticateLocalPlayer(){

    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in

        if (viewController != nil) {
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else {
            println((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
        }
    }

}

func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
{
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}



//GameScene.Swift
import GameKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{
var playerScore = 0
func playerScoreUpdate() {
    playerScorelabel.text = "\(playerScore)"
}

func saveHighScore(high:Int) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(high, forKey: "highscore")
    //check if user is signed in
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {

        var scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "TF1G002ID") //leaderboard id here

        scoreReporter.value = Int64(playerScore) //score variable here (same as above)

        var scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]

        GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println("error")
            }
        })

    }
}



//GameOver.Swift
import GameKit

class GameOverScene: SKScene, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

//shows leaderboard screen
func showLeader() {
    var vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    var gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
    vc?.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Press Finger
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if node.name == "replay" {
            playSound(sound)
        }

        if node.name == "leaderboard" {
            showLeader()
        } 
    }
}

//hides leaderboard screen
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
{
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the GameKit framework into your app?
Go to your project -> General -> scroll until you see linked frameworks -> click the plus sign -> add GameKit framework by searching

[image]